# How to change an Windows Image^ attribute with C++

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I'm trying to change an Image that I've defined in XAML in C++.
Currently there is no reason for me not to simply define it as it is in XAML, but later on it will need to change, so I want to get that sorted now.

Anyways, here's the XAML:

```
    <Image x:Name="playerBot"
                       Width="25"
                       Height="25"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Square Button.png"
                       Stretch="Fill"
                       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform TranslateX="0"
                                            TranslateY="0"
                                            Rotation="0"/>
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
```

What I have is a class which stores position data and an Image^ for the Image^ defined in XAML.

Sprite.cpp - note that the variables have been defined fine in Sprite.h

```
image = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->Path + image;
auto img = ref new BitmapImage;
img->UriSource = ref new Uri(image);
m_image = ref new Image;
m_image->Source = img;
m_image->Width = m_width;
m_image->MaxWidth = m_width;
m_image->MinWidth = m_width;
m_image->Height = m_height;
m_image->MaxHeight = m_height;
m_image->MinHeight = m_height;
```

And finally my 2 attempts to change the Image^ defined in XAML in InGamePage.cpp:
Attempt 1:

```
String^ img = "Assets//Main Screen Background.png";
player = new Robot(img, 25, 25, 0, 0, 10, 0.5);
playerBot = player->getImage();
```

Attempt 2:

```
String^ img = "Assets//Main Screen Background.png";
player = new Robot(img, 25, 25, 0, 0, 10, 0.5);
playerBot->MaxWidth = player->getWidth();
playerBot->MaxHeight = player->getHeight();
playerBot->Source = ref new BitmapImage(ref new Uri(Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->Path + img));
```

What these two methods do is either absolutely nothing (method one) or simply seem to delete the image/make it invisible (method two).

img is definitely the right file location, as I've used it in XAML earlier and it worked fine.

Comment: If the Robot class doesn't subscribe the Image.ImageFailed event then you can't hear it scream about the uri you used.  Which isn't valid, your XAML got it right.

Comment: So I ought to add in an

        if(!player->getImage()->ImageFailed){
            // Do code here
        }

right?